# Hotkey creating using keyboard library

Tags: python, autohotkey, hotkeys

So i am currently running a pyautogui script that has an autoclicker, and i wanted to implement a hotkey that when pressed, will stop the code no matter if vsc is opened or closed, how can I do that using Keyboard library

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple:

```
import keyboard
import sys

keyboard.add_hotkey('s', lambda: sys.exit()) #adds hotkey so that whenever you press the key s, the program exits
```